# Tried to open image but getting permission denied error

Tags: python

*****EDIT*****
I tried a different picture that had the proper file extension and the below image is what I get. Can anyone explain what's happening?

[image]I'm trying to open file images using PIL but am getting the error below. I've tried making sure that my ide had permisions and the file was open to everyone. I googled this but got solutions like chmod and chown, but they lead me down another rabbit hole with its own set of problems. I'd be really grateful if anyone could help me out. My goal is to display an image.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Dante\\Pictures\\Python_flowers'
```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.image as mpimg

from PIL import Image



img = mpimg.imread('C:\\Users\\Dante\\Pictures\\Python_flowers')

print(img)
```

********888EDIT 2 This code got my image to show up************

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Dante\\Pictures\\disco.jpg')

img.show()
```

Comment: The user running this program doesn't seem to have the right set of permissions. The user who copied the image there and the one running the code might be different.
You may want to change the permissions with: 
From command line 
`chmod 666 Python_Flowers`

Comment: Is "Python_flowers" the correct filename? Usually, on Windows, files have an extension such as `.png` or `.jpg`. If "Python_flowers" is a folder containing your actual images, then imread won't work.

Comment: You will also get this error if `C:\Users\Dante\Pictures\Python_flowers` is a folder and not a file.

Comment: I changed pictures and made sure it had the right file extension and isn't a folder. Can anyone tell me what's happening now?

Comment: But the console image is showing data, so the `print(img)` seem to work. I cannot see the error you say in the console. Also can you update your code so we can see that you are actually opening a n image file?

Comment: make sure the image file is not opened by  any other program or process, and if you are opening the file in code make sure you properly close it with close method or delete that object before accessing again